# Prevent Observer from firing on log out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I needed a way to send an email anytime a user updates their profile info (name, email, phone, address etc...) on the website.

Everything is working great except for this.

> Observer action is being called when user logs out.

When the user logs out the UserObserver sends the email that the account has been updated.

How can I prevent this from happening?

It looks like my `remember_token` on the users table changes every time I log out. Is there a way to exclude that from the Observer? That's the only thing I can see that could be causing the issue.

Here is the Observer:

```
 public function updating(User $user)
    {
        $current_name    = $user->fullName();
        
        if ($user->isDirty(['first_name'])) {
            // first name has changed
            $new_first_name = $user->first_name;
            $old_first_name = $user->getOriginal('first_name');
        }
        //....etc...
        Mail::to('xxx@xxx.com')
                ->send(new UserInfoUpdated(
                        $current_name,
                        $new_first_name ?? null,
                        $old_first_name ?? null,
                ));
    }
```

I'm using Laravel 8 and Php 7.4

Comment: After the remember_token is changed on log out the email fires.

Comment: Does this solves your problem? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/issues/449#issuecomment-431140096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the updated fields by calling getChanges() on the user object received in the event:

```
$field_updated = $user->getChanges()   // ['remember_token'=>'', 'updated_at' => '']
```

If $field_updated array include only remember_token & updated_at then don't send an email.